# findAndModify in Mongoskin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I cant get findAndModify to work with Mongoskin! 
This is probably dead simple, but what is wrong with this line?

```
var projections = {company: 1, ...};
db.clients.findAndModify({demo: false}, projections, {$set: {sms_sent: 0}}).toArray(function(err, docs) { 
... }
```

I get thrown a 'TypeError: object is not a function'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAndModify` is not returning `cursor`, so instead of calling `.toArray()` you should pass your callback directly as the last argument of `findAndModify` [see `node-mongodb-native` docs](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native#find-and-modify):

```js
collection.findAndModify(query, sort, update, options, callback)
```

Or, in your case:

```js
db.clients.findAndModify({
  demo: false
}, projections, {
  $set: { sms_sent: 0 }
}, function(err, doc) { 
  // doc is a single document, not an array
}
```